# How can I run terminal commands on my Ubuntu guest from host Mac?

Tags: ubuntu, mac

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 using Virtualbox on my MacBook Air (Mojave).

I want to run a command, say `top`, on the guest Ubuntu terminal from my Mac (I assume that in doing so, I will get the output of the said command on the Mac terminal).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have networking properly set up on your Ubuntu virtual machine, there are a few steps you need to do.

First, you need to provide a way to connect a terminal to your Ubuntu VM.  Generally, this is done through SSH.  However, by default, there is no SSH server installed.  You can run the following command to install the Open SSH server:

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

Enter your password and accept any prompts.  Once the install is finished, you need to start the server.  You can use the following command:

```
sudo service ssh start
```

From your Mac, open a terminal.  The Mac Terminal app is in the Utilities folder in Applications. To open it, either open your Applications folder, then open Utilities and double-click on Terminal, or press Command - spacebar to launch Spotlight and type "Terminal," then double-click the search result.  You can also use a third party terminal if you want.

From inside the terminal, SSH into your Ubuntu machine with the following command:

```
ssh <insert name or IP here>
```

The first time you SSH into a machine, you will be prompted and asked if you trust the machine.  Accept and you will be remotely connected to your Ubuntu machine.

At this point you can type in any commands you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I may be pushing, but how can I run the terminal command from within a Python program? As in, instead of using my Mac Terminal, I want to be able to run the commands from within a Python script. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AnubhavDinkar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586106/perform-commands-over-ssh-with-python

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `ssh` to connect to the Ubuntu VM from your MacOS? Some mroe details [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145997/trying-to-ssh-to-local-vm-ubuntu-with-putty).

Top answer from that link:

```
VirtualBox will create a private network (10.0.2.x) which will be connected to your 
host network using NAT. (Unless configured otherwise.)

This means that you cannot directly access any host of the private network 
from the host network. To do so, you need some port forwarding. In the network preferences 
of your VM you can, for example, configure VirtualBox to open port 22 on 127.0.1.1 (a 
loopback address of your host) and forward any traffic to port 22 of 10.0.2.1 (the internal 
address of your VM)

This way, you can point putty to Port 22 of 127.0.1.1 and VirtualBox will redirect this 
connection to your VM where its ssh daemon will answer it, allowing you to log in.
```